# Upload project in github subfolder

Tags: java, git, github

I'm a student, so I want to upload all my different java exercises in ***github***. I've got a ***repository*** called "OOP" and several ***subfolders*** one of them - "Exercises". I am also on Windows using Intellij IDEA.

#### *Is there any way that I can upload my projects into the subfolder "Exercises" by using ***git***?*

Thank you so much!

Comment: And you can't use github CLI? Because then it's pretty straightforward

Comment: @prakasht could you please explain what are the steps? Because I don't know what to write, nor can find any understandable tips.. :/

Comment: I'd strongly recommend for you to go through a decent quick tutorial for git. For this specific problem, here is the list of steps you need to do. 1. Setup git on your local machine 2. Clone the OOP repository to your local system. 3. Manually copy and paste your exercises into the OOP/Exercises folder 4. Push these new changes to your repository upstream. (Using `git push` or using UI, depends on whether you're using CLI or a GUI tool)

Answer (score 1):

For beginners, I recommand using [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/). You add your files, commit and push using the user interface.